# Jquery select checkbox automatically

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table with multiple rows. If a user enters a value in an input in one of the cells, then I'd like the corresponding checkbox to be automatically selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/BXxhV/1/

I suspect that its something to do with the closest method that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do `parent().find()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('.this_payment').live('change keyup',function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.trans-selected').prop("checked", ($(this).val() > 0));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  $('.this_payment').keyup(function () {
      $(this).prev('.trans-selected').prop("checked", ($(this).val() > 0));
  });
});
```

[See here for updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BXxhV/11/)

Answer (score 0):

try the working code here [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXxhV/10/), you can use `prev()` instead of `closest()`

Comment: That example doesn't check the checkboxes for me

Comment: it worked for me, i changed the value of first field to 5 and the checkbox got checked,similarly i changed the second field to 8 and same result

Comment: Strange. The checkboxes don't do anything for me in Chrome (15.0.874.121)

Comment: No, that's ok. I just realized by checking that `.val() > 0`, the checkbox will only be checked if numbers are entered. If letters are entered (which is what I was doing), the checkboxes won't update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('.this_payment').live('change keyup',function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.trans-selected').prop("checked", ($(this).val() > 0));
    });
});
```